# grep substring between quotes

Tags: shell, grep, string

Let's say I have a string like this:

```
title="2010-09-11 11:22:45Z"
```

How can I `grep` the date itself and disregard the quotes/title/`Z`?

The file can contain more strings like:

```
randomstring
title="2010-09-11 11:22:45Z"
title="disregard me"
```

So I only want to `grep` timestamps with a single `grep` command.

Comment: `sed 's/.*="\(.*\)"/\1/'`

Comment: @Groxxda thanks, but is it possible in `grep`, too?

Comment: `grep -o '".*"' | tr -d '"'`

Comment: I don't get why this question is downvoted so often. It's a simple question: `grep` timestamps using one command only.

Comment: Are hours and day always two digits?

Comment: @polym This is probably being downvoted for a few reasons. 1) your original question mentioned html, and you should not attempt to regex through html. 2) you altered your question after it had been answered, to which the most upvoted answer is no longer a solution to the question. 3) this also is starting to sound like an X/Y problem, but this is just my own feeling, and probably not downvote worthy.

Comment: @Groxxda hours and days are always like it's represented above.

Comment: It's unclear whether the data is a shell script file or some structured data format like XML. Depending on this, there would be smarter ways of extracting the needed data other than using `grep`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With `GNU grep`, you can do:

```
$ echo 'title="2010-09-11 11:22:45Z"' | grep -oP 'title="\K[^"]+'
2010-09-11 11:22:45Z
```

Comment: no explanation, what is K?

Comment: @ButtleButkus: `\K` is PCRE syntax, which don't include anything in left side of `\K` in matching result, or in Perl way, don't include in `$&`.

Comment: thanx a lot man. If you could include also that each flag it's doing.. Would be perfect.

Answer (score 6):

If input would be in this format only then below command will easily solve your problem

```
echo "title=\"2010-09-11 11:22:45Z\"| cut -d '"' -f2
```

Answer (score 4):

```
grep -oP '[0-9-]{10} [0-9:]{8}' filename
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work only on the GNU version of `grep`:

```
<file.html grep -oP "(?<=title\=\")\d+-\d+-\d+"
```

Example on regex101 [here](http://regex101.com/r/fM9fC4/1).

Answer (score 0):

The command to select anything between quote is:

```
echo 'title="2010-09-11 11:22:45Z"' | grep -oP "(?<=\").*(?=\")"
```

If you want to select only if the text inside double quote match a particular regex, then replace `.*` with that regex.

For example,

```
echo 'title="2010-09-11 11:22:45Z"' | grep -oP "(?<=\")[0-9-]{10} [0-9:]{8}Z(?=\")"
```

Will match the timestamp but not the `disregard me` text.